# qemu running powerpc u-boot failed

Tags: linux, qemu, powerpc

I'm trying to emulate freescale powerpc with QEMU,but faced some problem.
When I try to run ppc u-boot,it fails with the infomation below:

```
$ qemu-system-ppc -M ppce500 -nographic -kernel u-boot
qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0xeff40000

NIP eff40000   LR 00000000 CTR 00000000 XER 00000000
MSR 00000000 HID0 00000000  HF 00000000 idx 1
TB 00000000 05858550 DECR 00000000
GPR00 0000000000000000 0000000000fffff8 0000000000000000 00000000f1800000
GPR04 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000045504150 0000000000000000
GPR08 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
GPR12 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
GPR16 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
GPR20 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
GPR24 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
GPR28 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
CR 00000000  [ -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  ]             RES ffffffff
FPR00 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
FPR04 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
FPR08 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
FPR12 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
FPR16 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
FPR20 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
FPR24 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
FPR28 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
FPSCR 00000000
 SRR0 00000000  SRR1 00000000    PVR 80210030 VRSAVE 00000000
SPRG0 00000000 SPRG1 00000000  SPRG2 00000000  SPRG3 00000000
SPRG4 00000000 SPRG5 00000000  SPRG6 00000000  SPRG7 00000000
CSRR0 00000000 CSRR1 00000000 MCSRR0 00000000 MCSRR1 00000000
  TCR 00000000   TSR 00000000    ESR 00000000   DEAR 00000000
  PIR 00000000 DECAR 00000000   IVPR 00000000   EPCR 00000000
 MCSR 00000000 SPRG8 00000000    EPR 00000000
 MCAR 00000000  PID1 00000000   PID2 00000000    SVR 00000000
 MAS0 00000000  MAS1 00000000   MAS2 00000000   MAS3 00000000
 MAS4 00000000  MAS6 00000000   MAS7 00000000    PID 00000000
MMUCFG 00000000 TLB0CFG 04110200 TLB1CFG 101cc010
[1]    13621 abort (core dumped)  qemu-system-ppc -M ppce500 -nographic -kernel u-boot
```

As the error message shows: qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0xeff40000.It's Strange.**The u-boot I tried is ok on powerpc e500 board.What's more,I have run powerpc linux kernel successfully whih qemu-system-ppc.**
*The version of my qemu is the latest 2.3.50, and I've tried 1.7 have the same problem.*
Is there anybody faced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in 2.3.50 ([bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1481750)) with this effect.
It has been fixed in more recent qemu releases. 
Why it breaks in v1.7, I don't know. (are you sure?)